# Go Channel reading and writing stuck in infinite loop

Tags: go, channel, beego

First of all, I want to make Long Polling notification system. To be more specific, I will make http request, and response will be returned only if map channel is `true`.

This is the code block I used:

```
var MessageNotification = make(map[string]chan bool, 10)

func GetNotification(id int, timestamp int) notification {
    <-MessageNotification["1"]

    var chat_services []*models.Chat_service
    o := orm.NewOrm()

    _, err := o.QueryTable("chat_service").Filter("Sender__id", id).RelatedSel().All(&chat_services)

    if err != nil {
        return notification{Status: false}
    }
    return notification{Status: true, MessageList: chat_services}
}

func SetNotification(id int) {
    MessageNotification[strconv.Itoa(id)] <- true
}
```

This is controller block :

```
func (c *ChatController) Notification() {

data := chat.GetNotification(1,0)

c.Data["json"] = data
c.ServeJSON()

  }


func (c *ChatController) Websocket(){


    chat.SetNotification(1)

    c.Data["json"] = "test"
    c.ServeJSON();

}
```

function names and variable created for test.

No error occurred. Thanks for your help.

Comment: How are you calling `SetNotification`? There's no loop in your code so it's probably a blocking channel. Can you share some more code?

Comment: I added code. Do you think i need loop ? does   `<-MessageNotification["1"]` code make program wait or am i wrong ?

Comment: How are you calling `Notification` and `Websocket` functions?

Comment: These are controller.I use beego framework and beego callback controller function according to url.(for example localhost:8080/chatinfo )

Comment: You should add beego tag to your question. Someone who knows it might be able to help out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not creating your channel.

```
var MessageNotification = make(map[string]chan bool, 10)
```

This line makes a map with capacity 10, but you're not creating the actual *channels* in the map.  As a result, `SetNotification["1"] is a nil channel, and sends and receives on nil channels block indefinitely.

You need to put in

```
MessageNotification["1"] = make(chan bool)
```

You can include a size if desired (and I have a hunch your "10" in the map make was supposed to be the buffering for that channel).  This can even be done conditionally:

```
func GetNotification(id int, timestamp int) notification {
    if _, ok := MessageNotification["1"]; !ok { // if map does not contain that key
        MessageNotification["1"] = make(chan bool, 10)
    }

    <-MessageNotification["1"]
    // ...
}

func SetNotification(id int) {
    if _, ok := MessageNotification[strconv.Itoa(id)]; !ok { // if map does not contain that key
        MessageNotification[strconv.Itoa(id)] = make(chan bool, 10)
    }

    MessageNotification[strconv.Itoa(id)] <- true
}
```

This way the first location that tries to access the channel adds it to the map and properly makes the channel, so sends and receives on it will actually function.